# Files randomly disappear from my bucket while still downloadable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a mobile app from where the User is able to create a product with some photos.

The logic I have implemented is as following :

- All photos are stored in Firebase Storage
- The product is stored in Firebase Firestore, along with the download URL of each photos

And I'm a little confused because some of my files are not listed anymore in my bucket, **while I'm still able to download them via their URL**.

This happens pretty randomly as sometimes it concerns very old files, and sometimes very recent files.

Is it the right way to attach Storage files to Firestore documents ?
What am I possibly missing here ?

Comment: "The file aren't lister in Cloud storage" -> Have you deleted the files? How long the file are still downloadable?

Comment: Hi Guillaume, no I haven't deleted the files I am referring to. And these files are downloadable forever I guess ? Because I have configured the "standard" option for this storage.

Comment: So, how can you say that the files are not listed in the bucket? How do you validate that?

Comment: Because I only have 10 photos uploaded in my bucket, and currently 5 are missing while I’m still able to display them via their download URL which I have stored in Firestore.

Comment: Are you performing a bucket listing, and if so, can you provide the request parameters here? (You can leave off the bucket name if you like.)

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm using the Firebase Console to list all files in my bucket.

Comment: I don't know if that can help you Mike, but here is the request loaded in my Web browser :
This is the request my Web browser is loading :
https://firebasestorage.clients6.google.com/v0/b/xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/o?prefix=images%2Fproducts%2Fuploads%2Fxxxxxxxx%2F&internal_legacy=true&delimiter=%2F&maxResults=50